# Integration testing with Jetty and Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven

I use Spring, Hibernate and org.mortbay.jetty jetty-maven-plugin for integration tests. After integration tests running, I have exception. I apply `mvn verify`. Integration tests run fine. Part of stack trace here:

```
2014-05-08 20:41:00.771:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:stopped o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/D:/projects/pr_name/},D:\projects\pr_name2014-05-08 20:41:00.822:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED qtp509332906{8<=8<=8/254,0}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/QueuedThreadPool$1 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/QueuedThreadPool$1 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.doStop(QueuedThreadPool.java:121)
```

My pom.xml has:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.ws-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.4.v20120524</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopPort>8050</stopPort>
                <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                <stopWait>10</stopWait>
                <contextPath>/</contextPath>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run-exploded</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What version of maven and java are you using?

Comment: Have you tried this with the latest jetty plugin?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I use java 1.7.0_51 and maven 3.1.1

Comment: The version 8.1.14.v20131031 of the jetty-maven-plugin has solved my problem. Thank you very much)